# Sharing file using torrent

Tags: file-transfer, bittorrent

I have a large file (~1 TB) I want to share with a friend. I found that the best way to do that is to make a private torrent and share it with my friend. The problem is I am inside a university network. Can somebody tell me how/if it is possible for me to be visible to my friend to seed the torrent I created?

PS : I created the torrent using the instructions [here](http://lifehacker.com/5952148/how-to-create-a-super-private-bittorrent-community-for-you-and-your-friends). But towards the end of the article, it says that you have to change the settings of your router to forward ports. (explained [here](http://lifehacker.com/5831841/know-your-network-lesson-4-accessing-your-home-computers-from-anywhere#portforwarding)).

Can somebody please help me with that?

Comment: What is exactly your problem with the explanation given in [that](http://lifehacker.com/5831841/know-your-network-lesson-4-accessing-your-home-computers-from-anywhere#portforwarding) link. If we don't know where you're getting in trouble we can't help you. For example if you have uTorrent and you set it to a specific port you need to set the port forwarding in the router for that port. The problem if that you probably don't have control over the router (because of the university network). Maybe you're better of setting up a [BTSync folder](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync‎).

Comment: I tried to achieve the same goal, but failed at first: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/562320/install-deluged-and-deluged-console-in-a-debian-vm-and-serve-new-torrent-in-tran

Answer (score 0):

The U can block, not only using the port, but on the content, so I would suggest requiring mandatory encryption in both your and his torrent app to prevent being blocked on content.

Comment: I think the best way now is to tunnel the torrent traffic through an SSH connection using encryption on the data...

Comment: I started using bitsync.... but in some cases, my device cannot see a  particular other device that I have shared data on... is there a way to check if that device is visible to relay servers?

Comment: I take it you did add the folder and secret on that device? In the `Devices`-tab you can see the devices with which this device has synced (not necessarily all devices in your 'cloud'). It the other device is on, and you don't see it, it might also be blocked. Are both devices within the same network or is one device outside the uni-network?

Comment: @Rik Yes I added the folder and secret. The devices are on different networks.

Comment: @UnadulteratedImagination You say `in some cases, my device cannot see a particular other device`. Do you mean that **it is** *sometimes* seen from inside your network? Or it is **never** seen? If it is never seen it could still be that traffic is blocked. You could look in the history-tab to see if there are errors (on both clients). I've read there should be a logging options somewhere but i haven't found that on the Windows-client.

Comment: @Rik within a network I can always see the devices, the problem is when one of them is inside a network. Is there a good documentation to help me with this ?

Comment: @UnadulteratedImagination I think (in your last comment) you meant the device **outside** the network is not seen (or inside another network)? [here](http://btsync.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/BitTorrentSyncUserGuide.pdf) is some documentation. And [here](http://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/17782-bittorrent-sync-faq-unofficial/) is the unofficial faq.

Comment: @Rik No where in the documentation does it say what tracker server Bit torrrent sync uses. Now, how do I make sure that my computer is able to connect to a tracker server ?

Comment: @UnadulteratedImagination The relay servers are listed [here](http://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/19214-trouble-with-rotuer/#entry50004). In that post are also the requirements listed for normal operation (with a relay server). BTW It is also possible to define predefined hosts in the [properties](http://i.imgur.com/XdNq2Yo.png) of the folder preferences. (not sure if that can help you further)

Comment: @Rik Thanks... I think I know what the problem is. Most probably btsync wasn't using the U's proxy servers to connect to the trackers and that's why it wan't visible to me.